# Setting up a One To ManyJoins Against a Bridge Table using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Am new to JPA...

I have the following preexisting tables inside a MySQL 5 database:

- App
- User
- User_App_Bridge

The relationship(s) are mapped to the User_App_Bridge table (as the name implies, a bridge) amongst App and User as a One to Many cardinality.

The E-R diagram:

User ------ User_App_Bridge------ App

1 User is associated with many apps inside the User_App_Bridge table.

1 App is associated with many users inside the User_App_Bridge table.

The DDL for the User_App_Bridge table:

```
CREATE TABLE `User_App_Bridge` (
    `User_App_Bridge_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `User_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `App_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`User_App_Bridge_Id`),
    KEY `App_Id` (`App_Id`),
    KEY `User_Id` (`User_Id`),
    CONSTRAINT `user_app_bridge_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`App_Id`) REFERENCES `App` (`App_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Lets say that I have the following JPA Annotated Classes which are mapped to these tables:

```
@Entity
public class App {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "App_Id")
    private long appId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable
    (
        name = "UserAppBridge",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="App_Id", referencedColumnName = "App_Id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="User_Id", referencedColumnName = "User_Id") }
    )
    private List<User> users;

    @Column(name = "App_Name")
    private String appName;

    // Getters & Setter methods
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "User_Id")
    private long userId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable
    (   
       name = "UserAppBridge",
       joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="User_Id", referencedColumnName = "User_Id") },
       inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="App_Id", referencedColumnName = "App_Id", unique = true) }
    )
    private List<App> apps;

    @Column(name = "User_Name")
    private String userName;

    // Getters & Setter methods
}

@Entity
public class UserAppBridge {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "User_App_Bridge_Id")
    private long userAppBridgeId;

    @Column(name = "User_Id")
    private long userId;

    @Column(name = "App_Id")
    private long appId;

    // Getters & Setter methods
}
```

Question(s):

1. Is this (the block inside the @JoinTable) the correct way to do the one to many mapping for User and App entites with the UserAppBridge?
2. Inside the @JoinTable should the column & referencedColumnName be assigned to the SQL value (e.g. name="User_Id" , referencedColumnName = "User_Id")
   or should it be the Java reference name (e.g. name="userId" , referencedColumnName = "userId")?
3. Inside the inverseJoinColumns code black, is the unique = true necessary (what is it for)?
4. Do I need to do anything else inside the UserAppBridge class (for connecting to App and User)?

Thank you for taking the time to read this...

Comment: Don't you have a `ManyToMany` relationship User-App? Basically, as long as you do not have any additional fields in the Bridge, you could remove the `UserAppBridge` entity, in which case mark the relationship in User as `ManyToMany`.

Answer (score 4):

The answers for your questions:

1.No, it is not. You need to create a oneToMany mapping between User and UserAppBridge, and oneToMany mapping between App and UserAppBridge. Here is the code:

In User entity:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserAppBridge> userAppBridgeSet;
```

In App entity:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "app")
    private Set<UserAppBridge> userAppBridgeSet;
```

In UserAppBridge entity:

```
    @Entity
    @IdClass(UserAppBridgeId.class)
    public class UserAppBridge{

        @Id
        @Column(name = "User_App_Bridge_Id")             
        private long userAppBridgeId;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "User_Id")
        private long userId;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "App_Id")
        private long appId;

        @ManyToOne
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="User_Id", referencedColumnName="User_Id")
        private User user;

        @ManyToOne  
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="App_Id", referencedColumnName="App_Id")  
        private App app;

        // Getters & Setter methods
    }
```

In UserAppBridgeId class:

```
    public class UserAppBridgeId{

        private long userAppBridgeId;
        private int userId;
        private int appId;  

        // Getters & Setter methods 
    }
```

For more information on how to create advanced manyToMany relationship please see a [wiki link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns)

2. It should be an SQL names
3. With "unique=true" you are forcing a oneToMany relationship, without a "unique=true" it would be manyToMany.

Explanation: 
Lets have a following piece of code:

```
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable{
        //Here should be the table name and not the entity name
        name = "User_App_Bridge",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="User_Id", referencedColumnName = "User_Id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="App_Id", referencedColumnName = "App_Id", unique = true) }
    }
    private List<App> apps;
```

if there is a "unique=true" attribute, your mapping table can have only unique App_id (the same App_id can not occure more then once in mapping table), while it can have any User_id (same User_id can occur more then once in mapping table). What this means, is that one User_id may have assigned more App_id, while a single App_id may have assigned only one User_id. Hence you force a oneToMany relationship.

4. Yes, you do. As shown in answer 1 , you will have to create an Id class for UserAppBridge entity and also add a mapping for User and App entities

Comment: Thank you so much... So, basically, I removed the @JoinTable sections from my App & User classes (as you instructed)... Considering that the database is already populated. How can I query a list of all apps based on a user and a list of users based on apps? How would I use the UserAppBridgeId class?

Comment: If you have a "user" then you can simply call its "userAbbBridgeSet" and from here you will get an "app" ( [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4d3f72a90df700b41c08#file-gistfile1-txt) is the link how it could look like in the code). How would you use the UserAppBridgeId class? In this case you will need it only for reading. i.e. entityManager.find(userAppBridgeId,UserAppBridgeId.class), where userAppBridgeId is an instance of UserAppBridgeId.class.

Comment: Oh and btw, I know that you have asked how to create a mapping via UserAppBridge entity, BUT in this case I would recommend to drop UserAppBridge entity and just go with a simple manyToMany mapping ([here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5d78347bc4452065162c#file-gistfile1-txt) is the code sample). Your  User_App_Bridge table does not contains any additional columns and therefore there is no need to represent it as an entity.