# Hibernate generates wrong query for optional bi-directional OneToOne with JoinTable

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities :

- **RawDeviceMessage** which represents a raw message from a device
- **TagDetail** which represents the message after being parsed

A TagDetail may or may not be associated with a RawDeviceMessage, because it may be created directly without a raw message to parse. Thus, I have a **optional bi-directional OneToOne** relation between RawDeviceMessage and TagDetail.

In the database I have the following tables :

- **raw_device_message** (*id* + other columns)
- **tag_detail** (*id* + other columns)
- **tag_detail_has_raw_device_message** (*tag_detail_id* , *raw_device_message_id*) : this table is a JoinTable with the proper SQL constraints and foreign keys to enforce the OneToOne relation at the database level.

I have mapped my Java classes like that :

### RawDeviceMessage

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "raw_device_message")
public class RawDeviceMessage implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "rawDeviceMessage", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private TagDetail tagDetail;

    public RawDeviceMessage(){}

    public Long getId(){...}
    public void setId(final Long id){...}
    public TagDetail getTagDetail(){...}
    public RawDeviceMessage setTagDetail(TagDetail tagDetail){...}

}
```

### TagDetail

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag_detail")
public class TagDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(
        name="tag_detail_has_raw_device_message",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="tag_detail_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="raw_device_message_id"))
    private RawDeviceMessage rawDeviceMessage;

    public TagDetail() {}

    public Long getId(){...}
    public void setId(final Long id){...}
    public RawDeviceMessage getRawDeviceMessage(){...}
    public void setRawDeviceMessage(RawDeviceMessage rawDeviceMessage){...}
}
```

---

**The issue**

My issue is that when performing a find all on the RawDeviceMessage resource, Hibernate generates the wrong SQL query :

```
SELECT rawdevicem0_.id AS id1_15_,
       rawdevicem0_2_.tag_detail_id AS tag_deta0_37_,
FROM raw_device_message rawdevicem0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag_detail_has_raw_device_message rawdevicem0_2_ ON rawdevicem0_.id=rawdevicem0_2_.tag_detail_id
CROSS JOIN tag_detail tagdetail1_
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag_detail_has_raw_device_message tagdetail1_1_ ON tagdetail1_.id=tagdetail1_1_.tag_detail_id
WHERE rawdevicem0_2_.tag_detail_id=tagdetail1_.id
ORDER BY rawdevicem0_.id ASC
```

As you can see, in the first `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, the join condition is `rawdevicem0_.id=rawdevicem0_2_.tag_detail_id`

It tries to join `raw_device_message.id` with `tag_detail_has_raw_device_message.tag_detail_id` , which makes no sense and messes up with all the results.

Instead the join condition should be, `rawdevicem0_.id=rawdevicem0_2_.raw_device_message_id`
This condition would correctly join `raw_device_message.id` with `tag_detail_has_raw_device_message.raw_device_message_id`

I have shortened the query generated by hibernate to remove all unrelated fields, but in the generated query there is nowhere the column `raw_device_message_id`, so there is definitely something wrong.

**Is it an hibernate bug or am I doing my mapping wrong ?**

Comment: Please post your `findAll` query, at first glance I would say that you did something wrong there.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I'm using Spring's JpaRepository `List<T> findAll();` so I don't write any query myself.

Comment: What version of hibernate are you using? What DB are you using? I copied your entities into a postgres DB and told it to auto-export the schema. For me, the FK was created correctly in the database, and the generated queries also work as expected. I was unable to reproduce the behavior that you are describing.

Comment: I'm using Hibernate 5.1.0.Final and MySQL 5.7. I don't know why I have this error. I ended up by removing the bi-directional relation from RawDeviceMessage to TagDetail to "solve" my issue.

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose of tag_detail_has_raw_device_message table is only to link the two tables, then you can drop it. You can have One-to-One with just the two tables.
More details here - 
[Setting up a One To ManyJoins Against a Bridge Table using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269288/setting-up-a-one-to-manyjoins-against-a-bridge-table-using-jpa)

However if you want to have an intermediate mapping table, because it has some additional info for that relationship, then more details here.

http://what-when-how.com/hibernate/advanced-entity-association-mappings-hibernate/

Comment: I need to have a join table because my OneToOne association is optional. I don't want to have a column in tag_detail table filled with half of NULL values. I have read the docs in your second link. Under the sentence "You can map an optional one-to-one association to an intermediate join table with annotations" there is exactly the mapping that I'm using. However as I have found, it doesn't work because the generated SQL is wrong.

Comment: Yes. But that example does not describe the other side (mapping of Item to Shipment_item, it just shows the mapping of Shipmment to Shipment_item). Also, I am curious how you got this SQL, because RawDeviceMessage has lazy loading of TagDevice, so when I try the same code with findAll() I got a simpler SQL printed. Are the Entity mapping/classes correct?

Comment: I just set hibernate logging to trace and the sql got generated. Hibernated fetched the relation because I'm accessing it in a JPA criteria specification.