# Hibernate: How to create multi-column index on join table

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entity classes:

Taco

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="Taco")
public class Taco {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="taco_generator", sequenceName = "taco_seq")
    private Long id;
    
    private Date createdAt = new Date();
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, message="Name must be at least 5 characters long")
    private String name;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, message="You must choose at least 1 ingredient")
    @OneToMany()
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;
}
```

Ingredient

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="Ingredient")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force=true)
public class Ingredient {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;
    private String name;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) 
    private Type type;
    
    public enum Type {
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
    }
}
```

Hibernate creates a join table `Taco_Ingredient` for the given entities. I want to have multiple ingredients for a single taco.

So my `Taco_Ingredient` will look like this for a single Taco:

[image]

As they are not a multi-column key, Hibernate throws an exception when it tries to add another Taco, as the Ingredient will be duplicate.

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry 'LETC' for key 'Taco_Ingredient.UK_d8e4c1x7i3f3dmm4qemgcoi5y'
```

I am aware of @Index annotation, but as this join table is auto generated by Hibernate, I do not know how to add multi-column index to this join table.

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify a one-to-many relationship with join column, you can do as follows:

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "taco", targetEntity = Ingredient.class)
  private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "taco_id") // This is on the bearer side
  private Taco taco;
```

Comment: I don't have a join column, which is why Hibernate creates the join table Taco_Ingredient. I can create join column for both tables, but I wanted to know if it is possible to add indexes on join tables which are automatically created by Hibernate?

Comment: Well, if it is auto generated in `Taco_Ingredient.`, how do you form connection between the bridge-table and entity-table relationship?

Comment: I suppose the relation is based on primary keys of both entity tables. If you see Taco_Ingredient above, it has one column for each primary key of both entity tables: taco_id and ingredients_id

Comment: If you have a specific reason for setting up a bridge table for a one-to-many relationship, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269288/setting-up-a-one-to-manyjoins-against-a-bridge-table-using-jpa) with similar situation like yours, otherwise, I would recommend a simpler @JoinColumn